# CLLocationDegrees to String variable in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, geolocation

Given that the code

```
var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
```

returns a CLLocationDegrees Object, how can I store the value in to a variable so that I can apply it as the text of a label.

I can print the variable to the console without any issues but obviously that doesn't help me too much!

Looking through the valuable options through the autocomplete i see there is a description;

```
var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude.description
```

But this is returning me null?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466405/how-do-i-convert-corelocation-coordinates-to-a-string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can turn it to a String using this code:

```
var oneString = String(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
```

Comment: This works fine. Just make sure you are not passing an optional, which userLocation often is.

Answer (score 31):

since CLLocationDegrees is just a typedef for Double, you can easily assign it to a string var, ie:

```
var latitudeText:String = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
```

Comment: note: the explicit type definiton is just optional, the assignment works without it ofc

Comment: This is the easiest solution on this page. Also works with : `var lat = "\(result.location.coordinate.latitude)"`

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationDegrees?' to specified type 'String'

Answer (score 10):

```
let latitudeText = String(format: "%f", userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
```

Set the format paramater to your needs.

Answer (score 8):

nothing here worked for me.  The closest I got was "Optional(37.8)" for a latitude value, I think because the CLLocationCoordinate2D is an optional class parameter. Here is what I ended up doing to get a plain string:

```
let numLat = NSNumber(double: (self.myLocation?.latitude)! as Double)
let stLat:String = numLat.stringValue
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
var latData = String(stringInterpolationSegment: lat)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way of doing this is the following way.

1. Make an extension of CLLocationDegrees

   ```
   import Foundation
   import CoreLocation

   extension CLLocationDegrees {

    func toString() -> String {
         return "\(self)"
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use it like this

   ```
   print(searchedPlace.coordinate.latitude.toString())
   ```