# How do I convert CoreLocation coordinates to a String?

Tags: ios, string, oop, swift, core-location

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var user_lat = manager.location.coordinate.latitude
    var user_long = manager.location.coordinate.longitude
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I've tried `String(manager.location.coordinate.latitude)` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why can't you use string formatter?

Comment: @AnushaK I didn't even know what a formatter was until now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with format

```
let user_lat = String(format: "%f", manager.location.coordinate.latitude)
let user_long = String(format: "%f", manager.location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you must read it as a double and then convert it into string. Code should be something like this. Check the syntax, I haven't compiled the code.

```
let lat: Double = manager.location.coordinate.latitude
let user_lat : String = String(format:"%f", lat)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this (Swift 3)

```
guard let newLocation = locations.last else { return }

let latitude = Double(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
let longitude = Double(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)

let latString = (latitude < 0) ? "S" : "N"
let lonString = (longitude < 0) ? "W" : "E"

let coords = "\(latString) \(latitude) \(lonString) \(longitude)"

print(coords)
```